# SQL_ Counting value with a specific condition

Tags: sql

I would like to know how to count the ‘diagnosis_code’ with a condition.
In the table below the ‘diagnosis_code’ 2.3 from ‘RowNumber’ 1 to 6 will not be counted, because there is no ‘external_Condition’ in the previous row (and with the same ‘event_ID’).
However, the 2.1 in ‘ RowNumber’ 8 is counted because ‘external_Condition’ is flagged in previous ‘RowNumber’ 7.

Does anybody know what to do in this situation?

```
event_ID |  diagnosis_code | external_Condition |RowNumber
J1234567 |  2.3            | 0                  | 1
J1234567 |  2.3            | 0                  | 2
J1234567 |  2.3            | 0                  | 3
J1234567 |  2.3            | 0                  | 4
J1234567 |  2.3            | 0                  | 5
J1234567 |  2.3            | 0                  | 6
J1234567 |  NULL           | 1                  | 7
J1234567 |  2.1            | 0                  | 8
J1234567 |  NULL           | 1                  | 9
A1122357 |  2.3            | 0                  | 1
A1122357 |  2.2            | 0                  | 1
A1122357 |  2.2            | 0                  | 1
....
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please tag your database and also post your expected result

Comment: @Miki . . . SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" row unless a column specifies that information.  There is no column in your column with that information.  Also, you should show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

For count all the which is flagged:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(diagnosis_code) 
FROM 'Table_Name' 
WHERE external_Condition = 1
```

For count non repeated the which is flagged:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT diagnosis_code) 
FROM 'Table_Name'
WHERE external_Condition = 1
```